# ERROR in R: `[.data.frame`(y.data, , treat) : undefined columns selected - running mediation package

Tags: r

I am looking at the mediation of AUDITCEN --> INTERN through W1_cesd.

The relationship between AUDITCEN  and INTERN is quadradtic, but the relationship between AUDITCEN and W1_cesd is linear. I think this is causing me issues....

I am running:

```
dyad_id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
INTERN <- c(4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 6, 8, 6, 9, 9)
AUDITCEN <- c(5.9, -6.1, -9.1, -5.1, -7.1, -6.1, 0.9, -2.1, -7.1, 1.9)
W1_cesd <- c(25, 8, 5, 0, 5, 17, 10, 5, 5, 7)
GENDERKID<- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
C_AGE_DI <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
RACE_W <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
RACE_O <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
cesd <- data.frame(dyad_id, INTERN, AUDITCEN, W1_cesd, GENDERKID, C_AGE_DI, RACE_W, RACE_O)

library(mediation)
med.fit <-glm(W1_cesd ~ AUDITCEN + GENDERKID + C_AGE_DI + RACE_W + RACE_O, data=cesd )

out.fit <-glm(INTERN ~ W1_cesd+ poly(AUDITCEN, 2) + GENDERKID + C_AGE_DI + RACE_W + RACE_O, data=cesd )

results <-mediate(med.fit, out.fit, sims = 1000, boot = TRUE, treat = "AUDITCEN", control.value=-10, treat.value=0, mediator = "W1_cesd")
```

"results" produces the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(y.data, , treat) : undefined columns selected
```

My treatment variable does exist and the 2 models look fine. What is going wrong? Am I doing something wrong when I specify the quadratic association for my exp-out relationship?

Comment: Please provide a self-contained example code.

Comment: What package is `mediate` from? It doesn't appear to be part of the base packages...

Comment: @rmango  I've updated the question - apologies

Comment: @Z.Lin it is the mediation package. The question has been updated. Sorry for the confusion.